# How to serialize and deserialize lambda expression in F#?

Tags: c#, f#, lambda, serialization

I serialized lambda expressions in C# before. Now I wanna use F# instead of C# for serialization and deserialization.

I heard F# is better in this area. Is it true?
How can I do that with F#?

I’d appreciate even if you just suggested a correlated link.

Comment: can you collect all possible lambdas in a single array (statically)? if so just serialize the index in that array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard F# is act better in this area. Is it true?

Yes, the F# `Expr` type is marked as `[Serializable]`, so you can use for example binary serialization with it. On the other hand the C# (and VB) `Expression` is not `[Serializable]`, so to serialize it, you would either need to write quite a lot of code yourself, or use [a library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/217961/41071) for that.